# Can I redirect with method POST?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

On my website the user can answer questions. If the user clicks (GET request) on a question the question_detail view is called and rendes the question_detail.html template with a question object. If the user clicks on a submit button a POST request is sent to the same question_detail view that renders question_detail_solution.html. On this template the user can submit a comment form that is handled by the add_comment_to_question view. Once the comment is submitted I want the user to be redirected back to the same question_detail_solution.html template. It is important that the same context is passed into the template. Can I do a redirect with method POST from add_comment_to_question and is this best practice? Or should I define another view that renders question_detail_solution.html and redirect from question_detail (POST) and add_comment_to_question to this view? Or something else? Thank you for your answer!

```
def question_detail(request, pk):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=pk)
    user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    solved_questions = user_profile.solved_questions.all()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        context = {'question':question}
        return render(request, 'question_detail.html', context)
    else:
        try:
            answer = int(request.POST['choice'])
            is_correct = question.choice_set.get(id=answer).correct

            if is_correct:
                user_profile.solved_questions.add(question)

            form = CommentForm()

            context = {'question':question, 'answer':answer, 'correct':is_correct,
            'form':form}
            return render(request, 'question_detail_solution.html', context)
        except KeyError:
            messages.error(request, "Please make a choice!")
            context = {'question': question}
            return render(request, 'question_detail.html', context)

def add_comment_to_question(request, pk):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.question = question
            comment.author = request.user
            comment.save()
            return redirect('question_detail', pk=question.id)
    else:
        return HttpResponse("sth is wrong")
```

Comment: No. But why do you think you need the same context? You don't. Everything is now saved to the database; you redirect to the page with the ID of the question.

Comment: I want to display the users answer. This is not stored in the db. It's only stored wich questions he answerd but not what choice he/she clicked on. I want to pass answer und is_correct to the template.

Comment: Yes it is, you did `user_profile.solved_questions.add`.

Comment: Yes, If the user has answerd the question correctly it is added to the solved questions. But when the user clicks on the wrong choice it is not stored on wich wrong choice the user clicked. When the user submits a comment I want to keep this information stored in "answer" and show the wrong choice in red before and after submitting a comment.

Comment: But if it's not solved, why do you need to redirect? You should only redirect on a successful submission that modifies the database.